# Clarification needed regarding invoking a library

Tags: android

Please can you help me out with the usage of android libraries.

1. I hit a go button which needs to invoke a library.
2. Library in turn launches a login screen
3. The login screen accepts user id,password hits a URL and gives back a response(success/failure)

The code for the http post(which needs to be used as a library) is :

username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextusername);
         password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword);

```
     submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);


     submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(username.getText().length()>0 && password.getText().length()>0)
    {
        URLconnector ss = new URLconnector();
        ss.execute("http//ipchicken.com");
    }
}
```

});

```
}

private class URLconnector extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            try {



                List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



                UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        postParameters);

                httppost.setEntity(formEntity);

                HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response1.getEntity()
                                .getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }
                in.close();

                String result = sb.toString();
                response = result;
                System.err.println("My Response :: " + result);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result != null)
        {
        Intent tokenIntent = new Intent(mContext, tokenActivity.class);
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("responsedata",result);

        tokenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(tokenIntent);
        }
```

Comment: This really isn't an appropriate question for Stackoverflow. Now, if you included some code to show us what you've attempted thus far, it'd be a different story.

Comment: @DaveH , Sorry about that. I have added my code. Please can you help out.

Comment: I see you listed what you expect to happen, but what actually happens?

Comment: @AdamJohns, I added the above code as a library project to the other project which has my UI component, but got this error "Only a type can be imported. com.xyz.abc resolves to a package"

Comment: What line of code is pointed to from that error?

Comment: @AdamJohns I got in the import line"import com.xyz.abc" of my mainactiviyt of my project containing the UI component com.example.testgui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.xyz.abc;

Comment: I think I got the error, I did not mention the java file from the library project. So it is "import com.xyz.abc.filename"

Comment: @AdamJohns Since that is sorted out, could you help with how to approach the callbacks to and from the library project ?

Comment: So, the process you list above as 1,2,3 is what is supposed to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: @AdamJohns The main project consists of a button which invokes the http post library project, this in turn is supposed to launch a login screen and do validation. I am getting an error "the application testgui has stopped unexpectedly" when i run the app

Comment: Do you know how to look at the exception report in logcat? If so, post the exception report. The console dump of everything being executed likely has red exception code somewhere that lists what the problem is. A lot of times it is a null pointer exception.

Comment: I have added the java file of the library project on my main project's manifest btw, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: hmmm show me the code where you declare the activity in your manifest

Comment: Also, make sure you added the activity to YOUR application's manifest file. Not the library's manifest file.

Comment: @AdamJohns Yes, I have added the library project activity to My manifestfile of the application, the code of the app's manifest is: 
      <activity
            android:name="com.example.testgui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.xyz.abc.httpcommunicationhelper2.httpost"></activity>
  <activity android:name="com.xyz.abc.httpcommunicationhelper2.tokenActivity">
        </activity>

Comment: @AdamJohns Looks like it is working now, the issue was that I had the same name for the xml layouts (activity_main)for both the app and the library. I appreciate your help, thank you !

Comment: @AdamJohns would you mind deleting your previous comment, it ends up that I revealed the project name and used xyz.abc to keep it generic